# String Function in PHP

Tags: php

**String Function in PHP:**

```
$img = "WhatsApp Image 2019-11-18 at 17.15.42.jpeg | xyz.com/content/uploads/wcpa_uploads/image.jpg";
```

using string functions, how can I get complete text after **|** symbol, I mean only the complete url of image should be saved in variable.

Comment: Use `preg_replace` or `explode`

Comment: Why is this question upvoted? There is no attempt to self-solve this basic question.

Answer (score 0):

There are several methods for that. If you do not want to regex or split to array, try this:

```
$path = trim(substr(strstr($img, "|"), 1));
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way:

```php
trim(explode('|', $img)[1])
```